# Multiple condiotions in an IF Statement

Tags: c++

I'm getting an error that I don't understand since I'm new to C++. The `if` statement has something wrong in the condition:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string username;
    int password;

    cout << " Welcome User, Please Login." << endl;
    //Username
    cout << "Username: ";
    cin >> username;
    //Password
    cout << "\nPassword: ";
    cin >> password;

    if (username == 'admin' && password == '852456')
        cout << "Welcome." <<endl;
    else
        cout << "Wrong credentials." <<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Type mismatch, as you should see from the error message that you did not send us:((

Comment: `if (username == 'admin' && password == '852456')` is obviously wrong! Use `"` to specify string literals.

Comment: Definitely send us the exact text of the error. Just some advice to you as a potential new programmer... error messages are there to be read, not skipped over as just "an error." You'll learn how to understand what they mean with more practice.

Answer (score 5):

`if (username == 'admin' && password == '852456')`

should be

`if (username == "admin" && password == 852456)`

To use `'admin'` doesn't make sense, those markings are only for characters such as `char alpha = 'a'`. `"` are used for strings (multiple characters). Numbers don't need either of those, they are just numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Though the password declared as having type int

```
int password;
```

you are using multicharacter literals 'admin' and '852456'

```
if (username == 'admin' && password == '852456')
               ^^^^^^^^                ^^^^^^^^
```

which integer values are implementation defined.

According to the C++ Standard (2.14.3 Character literals)

> 1. ...An ordinary character literal that contains more than one c-char is a
>      multicharacter literal. A multicharacter literal, or an ordinary
>      character literal containing a single c-char not representable in the
>      execution character set, is conditionally-supported, has type int, and
>      **has an implementation-defined value**.

I think you was going to compare password with an integer literal and username with a string literal

```
if (username == "admin" && password == 852456 )
```

That is you have to use a string literal and integer literal.

You may use a single quote inside an integer literal provided that your compiler supports C++ 2014. For example

```
if (username == "admin" && password == 852'456 )
```

String literals are enclosed in double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using single quotes,you should have used double quotes as username is a string type not char type.Coming to password it's integer type.It won't demand for any kind of quotes either single or double.